# JS object to HTML data binding with Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a JS object constructed from XML.

How do I bind that JS object to html?

Example:
ViewModel:

```
  vm: {
    a: ko.observable()
  }
```

JS (of the model):

```
aObj : {
  item1: [ { n: 'a1', v: 'v1'}, { n:'a2', v:'v2' } ],
  item2: [ ]
}
```

JS (binding logic):

```
vm.a(aObj);
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="with: vm.a">
  <div data-bind="foreach: item1">
     <div data-bind="text: n"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cannot loop over the array elements of item1

What am I doing wrong? I just get the following computed DOM:

```
<div data-bind="with: vm.a">
  <div data-bind="foreach: item1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/tpLVC/2/ .

Do you get any errors in the console? In the html in the fiddle, notice that the with binding is `with: a` . If your top level viewModel has the a property, then you should use it like this.

If you have a top level viewModel with a `vm` property, only then will the `with: vm.a` work.